# php preg_match() multiple patterns

Tags: php, preg-match

Would be possible to return the result of preg_match under the same array index in case of multiple patterns. What I mean I have the following preg_match what is checking occurrences on different sub strings (`'&q'` , `'?q'` , `'&keywords'`).

```
preg_match('/&q=(.+?)(&|$)|\?q=(.+?)(\&|$)|\&keywords=(.+?)(\&|$)/', urldecode($test_string), $matches);
```

I would like to see all occurrences under `$matches[1]` to can exclude the following `if` statement.

```
if($matches){   
            if ($matches[1] != ''){
              $query_p = mysql_escape_string($matches[1]);      
            } elseif ($matches[3] != ''){   
              $query_p = mysql_escape_string($matches[3]);      
            } elseif($matches[5] != ''){
              $query_p = mysql_escape_string($matches[5]);
            }
         }
```

Comment: This looks like you are trying to extract elements from the query part of a url. There are specialized means for this, why do you want to use a regex?

Comment: Yes that would be the idea, to get query parts from url. Can you please point me to the right area.

Comment: Take a look at phps `parse_url()` function and `explode` the query part of the result by `&` characters:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify your regex and convert all non-intented capturing groups to non-capturing groups in your regex like this:

```
/[?&](?:q|keywords)=([^&]+)(?:&|$)/
```

**Alternatively** use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function to parse a query string.